# Sorting multiple columns when I click a column header

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I'm using Tablesorter 2.8.1 (Mottie's fork), and I have a HTML table similar to the following:

```
HEADER1   HEADER2
-------- ---------
A         5
C         1
B         4
A         1
```

When I click HEADER2, the table gets sorted by this column:

```
HEADER1   HEADER2
-------- ---------
C         1
A         1
B         4
A         5
```

I know I can sort both columns simultaneously by holding down the SHIFT key and clicking HEADER2 and then HEADER1, but what I really need to do is having both columns sorted when I click HEADER2. In other words, I need this to happen when I click HEADER2:

```
HEADER1   HEADER2
-------- ---------
A         1
C         1
B         4
A         5
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you are using jQWidgets or some other plugin to jQuery?  jQuery is not on version 2.8.1.

Comment: @RyanLynch thanks for pointing that out. I meant I'm using Tablesorter 2.8.1 (Mottie's fork).

Comment: Do you want HEADER1 to always sort with HEADER2? Maybe try the [`sortAppend` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortappend).